# Update/Merge all fields of a detached entity with new instance of same class - in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, merge

I've implemented the following inheritance.

```
abstract Superclass: ConnectionTechnologyDetails
Subclasses: SMTPDetails, AS2Details and FTPDetails
```

Instances of the subclasses are persisted with the JPA repositories of Spring. New data arrives from a front end form, saved in new instances of the subclasses.

Unfortunately I can't manage to update the persisted entites with the fields of the new instaces. Because I don't know the actual class of the instances I can't use their setters. Only the setters of the superclass ConnectionTechnologyDetails are available.

```
// getting the id of the persisted entity
Long connectionTechnologyDetailsDetachedId = connectionPersisted.getConnectionTechnology()
    .getConnectionTechnologyDetails()
    .getId();

// detach the persistent entity
ConnectionTechnologyDetails connectionTechnologyDetailsDetached = 
    connectionTechnologyDetailsRepository
    .findById(connectionTechnologyDetailsDetachedId).get();
```

I would like to update like that:

```
/** Update all fields with the fields of the 
*   new instance because I can't access
*  the setters and getters of the subclasses here.
*/

connectionTechnologyDetailsDetached
    .updateALlFieldsWith(
        connectionRequest
        .getConnectionTechnology()
        .getConnectionTechnologyDetails()
    );
connectionTechnologyDetailsRepository.save(connectionTechnologyDetailsDetached);
```

**Is there some method to update all fields or maybe a possibility to access the setters and getters of the subclasses?**

My solution so far: Get the specific subclass from the DiscriminatorColumn annotation of the subclasses. Then cast to the specific class and call manually all setters with the new values.

Comment: Interesting solution. So you'd pull up everything to the superclass instead of for example casting it to the correct subclass? Are you sure that's a smart idea?

Comment: I think I'll cast. The information therefore in which class I've to cast, is available in the Annotation DiscriminatorColumn. But a Method to merge all fields would be much more efficient because I've have to write down the calls for the setters.

Comment: Well any `BeanUtils` or similar will let you copy properties from one object to another.

Comment: Oh okay cool! I'm pretty knew to Java EE, Spring, etc. Something like this:  BeanUtils.copyProperties(this, anotherBean);
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring's BeanUtils.copyProperties(Source,Target) did the trick. Thanks